# why this code is not returning another print value from the source

Tags: python, lexer

```
keywords = ['PRINT']

class Lexer:
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source
        self.sourceLen = len(source)
        self.cur = 0
        pass
    def getChar(self):
        if self.cur < self.sourceLen:
            return self.source[self.cur]
             
        return ""

    def next(self):
        self.cur += 1
        pass
    def skipNewline(self):
        while self.getChar() == '\n':
            self.next()
    def skipWhitespace(self):
        while self.getChar() == ' ':
            self.next()
    def skipBlanks(self):
        while self.getChar() == ' ' or self.getChar() == '\n':
            self.next()


    def tokenize(self):
        self.skipBlanks()
        curToken = ''
        char = self.getChar() # P
        
        if char in '"Hello, world!"'.split():
            curToken = ''
            return

        while char != ' ':
            curToken += char
            self.next()
            char = self.getChar()

        if curToken in keywords:
            print({"Token":curToken})
            curToken = ''


    def start(self):
        self.skipBlanks()
        
        while self.cur < self.sourceLen:
            self.tokenize()




source = """
PRINT "Hello, world!"
PRINT "second line!"
"""

lexme = Lexer(source)
lexme.start()
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think it should?

Comment: Because you are only retuning an empty string or `None`.

Comment: @ScottHunter i want output like
{'Token': 'PRINT'}
{'Token': 'PRINT'}
 but i'm getting it like {'Token': 'PRINT'} .. . i'm not getting any error but i don't know where my code is stuck

Comment: I didn't ask *what* you wanted; I asked *why* you think this code should do that.